# Proving a term converges pointwise by the definition

Tags: convergence-divergence, pointwise-convergence

How would I show
$$f_n(x) = n^\alpha x^n (1-x)\qquad \text{for} \: x \in [0,1]$$ converges pointwise  to $0$ by the definition?
I showed that it converges for $x=0,1$ trivially, but I'm not sure how I would use the definition for the interior of the domain.

Comment: Can you see that $f_n(1/2) = n^\alpha (1/2)^n (1/2)$ converges?

Comment: Yep, since the exponential overpowers the algebraic term. I'm not sure how I would set it out formally for all $x$ in that domain, (I think informally we can just use some sort of squeeze law?)

Comment: if you are unsure about the asymptotic, you can rewrite $b^z$ as $\exp(z \log(b))$ for $b>0$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $|f_n(x)| \leq n^{\alpha}|x|^n$ for $x \in (0,1)$, then you need to recall that $\lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{n^{\alpha}}{x^n}} \to 0$ whenever $x > 1$.